# replacing data in a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, oledbconnection

I am trying to replace data in a dataset so i can add it back to a .DBF file. currently i can gather the new dataset but i don't know how to find and replace certain data. For instance, I want to replace 'ABC_123_TEST' by 'DEF_456_TEST' in the first column.

```
        try
        {
            string coonect = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\; Extended Properties = dBase IV; User ID =; Password =";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = coonect;
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM variable WHERE NAME LIKE @VAL1", con);
            cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL1", "%" + textBox5.Text + "%");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            
            cmd.Fill(ds);
            DataSet newData = ds.Copy(); //What should i do with this dataset


            con.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];    
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exp.Message);
        }
```

Comment: A DataTable has a Select method where you can filter the DataTable. It will return you an array of rows with the hits. Simply change those rows and use a TableAdapter again to apply those changes to the database. As alternative simply send an UPDATE sql command yourself to the database with the change you want to apply.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Allright i have changed my data but i would like to add it to the current database while keeping all the original data in the db, thanks!

Comment: It depends if the table(s) in the database have a primary key.   Since with a primary key you can have only one row in the database you cannot keep old and new.  If you do not have a primary key than you can keep both old and new.  It is recommend in this case you have a date on the row so you can tell differences of old and new values.